# jQuery DataTable is not showing the data

Tags: jquery, datatables

My jQuery DataTable does not list the JSON data. Why is that?

The HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Binalar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "http://127.0.0.1/HCAWebApp/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/demo_page.css";
            @import "http://127.0.0.1/HCAWebApp/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/demo_table.css";
        </style>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1/HCAWebApp/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/HCAWebApp/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#binalar').dataTable({
            "bProcessing" : true,
            "bServerSide" : true,
            "sAjaxSource" : "http://127.0.0.1/HCAWebApp/index.php/getbuildings"
        });
    }); 
</script>

    <style>
        body { padding: 15px 30px; }
        .alignleft { float: left; vertical-align:text-bottom; }
        .alignright { float: right; vertical-align:text-bottom; }
        td { width: 25% }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
                   <div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </a>
                  <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                    <li class='active'><a href="binalar">Binalar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="cihazlar">Cihazlar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="kullanicilar">Kullanıcılar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="gruplar">Gruplar</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">İlhan ŞUBAŞI <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Veritronik</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Seller</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="kullanicilar/logout">Çıkış</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
              </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
            </div><!-- /navbar --><div class='fdfg'>
    <div id="baslik">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom:-15px" class="alignleft">Binalar</h1>
        <h3 style="margin-bottom:-15px" class="alignright">+ Bina Ekleme</h3>   </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <hr>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="binalar">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="dataTables_empty">Veriler sunucudan yükleniyor.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The JSON data, it has `application/json` content-type.

```
{ "aaData" : [ [ "Ersin SEewrZA",
        "eseeza@veritrwqonik.werew"
      ],
      [ "İlhan ŞUBewrAŞI",
        "isuqbasi@veritrewonik.ewrew"
      ]
    ],
  "iTotalDisplayRecords" : 2,
  "iTotalRecords" : 2,
  "sColumns" : "FullName,Email",
  "sEcho" : 0
}
```

All the files are loading properly. And no JavaScript error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed `sAjaxSource` source to a relative path and it worked. `"sAjaxSource" : "../index.php/getbuildings"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are not requesting with the sEcho query parameter, and you are telling datatables to validate that the parameter matches..  test it out, if the parameter doesn't match it will just sit in "processing."

e.g:  `/HCAWebApp/index.php/getbuildings&sEcho=0` because you passed `"sEcho":0` in the init.

```
 $('#binalar').dataTable({
    "bProcessing" : true,
    "bServerSide" : true,
    "sAjaxSource" : "/getbuildings.json?sEcho=0"  ,  
    "sEcho": 0
    });
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/VbZhW/4/