# JQuery DataTables does not show data

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Problem:**

`DataTables` does not show any data. Ajax returns a json object, but `DataTables` does not display data

**Versions:**

`DataTables-1.9.4`

`jquery-1.9.1`

**Research:**

[jQuery DataTable is not showing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648777/jquery-datatable-is-not-showing-the-data)

[Data does not show in dataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260422/data-does-not-show-in-datatables)

**Data Tables Legacy Doc**

http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

**JQuery:**

```
$('#pd_ac_form_case_search_table').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource":  AjaxCaseSearch+"?sEcho=1",
    "aoColumns"  : [{ "mData": "employee" },
                  { "mData": "id" },
                  { "mData": "status" },
                  { "mData": "app_date" }],
    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
    "sEcho": 1,
    "fnServerParams" : function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "pd_form_search_type", "value": "ALL" } );
    }
});
```

**Json Object:**

Here is the json object data when inspected in chrome developer.

```
aaData: {employee: "Emp Name", id: "465456", status: "Application Saved", app_date: "1/11/2015"}
app_date: "1/11/2015"
employee: "Emp Name"
status: "Application Saved"
id: "465456"
iTotalDisplayRecords: "1"
iTotalRecords: "1"
sEcho: 1
```

**Attempts:**

I've tried different attempts of messing with the different parameters.

I've start with the basic configuration:

```
    $('#pd_ac_form_case_search_table').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource":  AjaxCaseSearch

    });
```

and worked to where I am now. Adding the `sEcho` parameter was my latest attempt after reading about it.

**Error:**

When I start searching for something I can see the ajax in chrome developer, but `DataTables` will say `processing...`

Comment: aaData needs to be an array of json objects...look at sample server response in the legacy doc link you posted. `[{ employee: "Emp Name"} ]`. Also, DataTables will add the sEcho param to the request, you only need to make sure you return the value in the response.

Comment: Okay that was exactly the problem, but now I'm still having the same problem with the DataTable not displaying the data. The issue is that when I displaying the data I have everything in a JSONObject and I do `JSONObject.toString()`. Well this indexes my aaData object so that it's "0" : {dataRow}... etc.... I'm going to work on this a bit. Thanks for the help though. Didn't realize my json was malformed.

Comment: Nope. JSON was properly formed.... I thought it wasn't when it was presented in Chrome developer, but when I looked at the response tab rather than the preview tab I could see that the JSON was formed properly.